# How to add text after return number_format in PHP?

Tags: php

I need to add text right after this number:

```
if( isset( $entry['103'] )) {
    return number_format (($entry['103'] * 0.6),0, ".", ",") ;
```

How can I do it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Concatenation? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: yes how to concatenate a text there?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to combine a text with a number like eg: User 3903810??

Comment: The code you provided is not your "try" to get the answer. That's why the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you out:

```
if( isset( $entry['103'] )) {
    $n = number_format (($entry['103'] * 0.6),0, ".", ",") ;
    $n = $n."Your text";
    return $n;
```